# Pass values into function for glutDisplayFunc

Tags: c++, glut

I'm trying to pass data in the form of an array to a function that is called by glutDisplayFunc.  Please let me know if/how this is possible or easy alternatives to achieve the same goal.  Eventually I will want to pass a lot of values into the drawing function.  Thank you!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#include <glut.h>

void Draw(int passedArray[]) { // This is probably wrong but just to give you the idea
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex3f(passedArray[1], passedArray[2], 0.0); // A point is plotted based on passed data
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void Initialize() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // Background color
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}


int main(int iArgc, char** cppArgv) {
    cout << "Start Main" << endl;
    glutInit(&iArgc, cppArgv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(250, 250); // Control window size
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
    glutCreateWindow("GA");
    Initialize();
    int passedArray[2] = {10, 20}; // create array
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw(passedArray)); // This is not how you do this, just to try to convey what I want
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only way I can think of is global variable.

Comment: I don't know how you want to use the array data, but if [this](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html) is the `glutDisplayFunc` that you refer to, then the only thing you can pass it is a function -- not an array. I guess you'll have to define a function that internally makes use of the array, and pass that function in the call to `glutDisplayFunc`.

Comment: @nhahtdh I thought global variables were generally frowned upon?  Is this an exception?

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO: I am totally aware of the disadvantage with global variable, but it is one of the solutions to the problem. Since it is not a good solution, I post it as a comment.

Comment: Switch into [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/) from GLUT/FreeGLUT unless not to late. Unless your are using depreciated OpenGL version API (OpenGL 1.0-1.5) GLUT is OK, but for OpenGL 2.0+ (with shaders) GLUT is horrible choose.  [Hire](https://learnopengl.com/) you can found information - how to use OpenGL now days.

Comment: You can start from [this](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle)

Answer (score 1):

Main point is that *only global variables make sense* with glut.

**Why?**

There is no reason to use local variables, for glut itself is global.
*glutInit* may be called only once per application. And so on.

**Boiling out**

For C++11 and higher.
Pass lambda instead of function pointer.
Example below shows how to pass lambda into loop body. By having lambda as a display function you may use capture section to pass whatever you like.

```
    // Include GLUT headers here as well

    #include <functional>

    typedef std::function<void()> loop_function_t;

    struct GlutArgs {
        loop_function_t loopFunction;
    };

    GlutArgs& getGlutArgs() {
        static GlutArgs glutArgs;
        return glutArgs;
    }

    void display() {
        getGlutArgs().loopFunction();
    }

    void init(int argc, char** argv) {
        // glutInit and friends goes here

        glutDisplayFunc (display);
    }

    void loop(loop_function_t f) {
        getGlutArgs().loopFunction = f;
        glutMainLoop();        
    }

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        init(argc, argv);
        int myVar = 1;
        loop([myVar](){
           glClear(...);
           doSomething(myVar);
        });
    }
```

For old C++ standards, all the same but instead of lambda just fill GlutArgs contents with your variables instead of lambda, and use them from *display* function directly.